# How to sync file in perforce only if client has older version?

Tags: perforce

I want to sync my work space to a cl but only those files on the work space that are older that the cl. Any files newer than the cl should be ignored. How can I do that? I need a command. Regards.

Comment: You mean, the only files you wish to update the files that were specifically modified by that particular changelist?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the use case right, suppose we have a file with 3 revisions:

    #3 change 300
    #2 change 200
    #1 change 100

And you want to apply your process to change 200, which is to sync it to 200 but with the constraint that you don't want to sync it backward.  I.e. if the file is currently synced to #0 or #1, you want to sync it to #2; if the file is currently synced to #2 or #3, you want to leave it alone.  And you want to apply this to all files in your workspace.

Is that right?

Comment: @SamStafford Yes. That's the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syncing to a changelist normally is very simple; you'd just do:

```
p4 sync @CL
```

But what you're looking for is to sync a changelist with the special exception that you don't want any revisions to go backwards.  You can get most of the way with this command:

```
p4 sync #have,@CL
```

I.e. "sync all revisions that are >=#have and <=@CL".

What this misses is files where #have is nonexistent (they will not be included in a range that uses #have).  Those are trickier, but this is one way to do it:

```
p4 -F "%code0% %depotFile%%depotRev%" sync -n @CL | grep "^318773588 " | sed -e "s/318773588 //" | p4 -x - sync
```

(If this looks like magic, it is -- the code0=318773588 is the message code emitted when a file is "added" by sync rather than being "updated", which only happens if there is no #have rev.  I got this number using the -e global option.)

---

An entirely different approach would be to take advantage of the fact that "sync" won't move the working revision backwards when a file is open for edit:

```
p4 edit //...
p4 sync @CL
p4 -F %depotFile%%workRev% opened | p4 -x - sync
p4 revert -a
```

This doesn't perform quite as well since opening all those files for edit and then reverting them will take a non-negligible amount of time if you have thousands of files, but it requires a bit less magic scripting.  The only slightly tricky part is that third line, which is saying "make my haveRev match my workRev for all opened files" -- that way the files that the sync tried to move backward (i.e. where haveRev is less than workRev) get reset to the higher haveRev before you revert.

Comment: This will sync the whole depot to the point in time when the cl was submitted. I want the command to ignore the files with a newer version than the **_CL_** version.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for that! So, 318773588 is a constant that wouldn't change right? I mean across perforce versions, and with different servers.

In short these two commands should do the work:
`p4 sync #0,@1234`
`p4 -F "%code0% %depotFile%%depotRev%" sync -n @1234 | grep "^318773588 " | sed -e "s/318773588 //" | p4 -x - sync`

Where 1234 is the CL and I want to sync all versions >=0.
What happens if I try `p4 sync #none,@1234`

Regards.

Comment: Also, in case I only want this operation on the files contained in the cl:
`p4 sync #0,@=1234`
`p4 -F "%code0% %depotFile%%depotRev%" sync -n @=1234 | grep "^318773588 " | sed -e "s/318773588 //" | p4 -x - sync`

Comment: My perforce says:  Invalid option: -F. It may not support the F option. Are there any alternatives? Thanks in any case.

Comment: -F is a client side feature, so just update your p4 executable.  The message code could in theory change but it hasn't in about 20 years so far, so you should be safe.

Comment: Also for "sync things in this change exactly that are newer than my haveRev" I think the syntax you want is "#>have,@=CHANGE".  Definitely getting into the deep magic.  :)

Comment: Well I can now confirm that "#>have,@=CHANGE" doesn't work.